# Multiplying lengths by a factor

Tags: pstricks, calculations

I am trying to create a `pspicture` where some lengths are calculated in dependency of the size of the `pspicture` and an included graphic but I am getting the following error message

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

when using the `\multiply` command with one of these length (see minimal example at the end). The previous `\multiply` command is working and I cannot figure out, why the second `\multiply` command does not work. I really hope somebody can help me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0cm,0cm)(17cm,24cm)
\newdimen{\FotoHeight}
\newdimen{\PictureHeight}
\PictureHeight=24cm
\settoheight{\FotoHeight}{\includegraphics[width=24cm]{picture.ps}}
\multiply\FotoHeight by 0.5 %This is working
\multiply\PictureHeight by 0.5 %This is throwing the error message
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error from the code (after adding `\usepackage{graphicx}`, of course). Anyway, neither operation works in the way you wish to.

Comment: I added the `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the example.

Answer (score 7):

No, neither is working.

Leaving out the `pspicture` which is not relevant, we can reduce the example to

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen{\FotoHeight}
\newdimen{\PictureHeight}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\PictureHeight}{24cm}
\setlength{\FotoHeight}{2cm}

\multiply\FotoHeight by 0.5 
\multiply\PictureHeight by 0.5

\end{document}
```

which prints

> .5 .5

as readily verified. You can't use a non integer factor for `\multiply`. So both dimensions are set to zero and the “illegal” tokens are printed.

What you should do is

```
\FotoHeight=0.5\FotoHeight
\PictureHeight=0.5\PictureHeight
```

By the way, you shouldn't declare `\newdimen` in the body of `pspicture` (I'm dubious if you need it at all), but in the document preamble.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. You are right, I do not actually need `\newdimen`, I used now `\newlength` and worked with `\setlength{FotoHeight}{0.5\FotoHeight}`. I did not stumble over any additional problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\PBox
\newlength\FotoHeight 
\newlength\PictureHeight 

\begin{document}
\sbox\PBox{\includegraphics[width=24cm]{picture.ps}}

\setlength\FotoHeight{0.5\ht\PBox}
\setlength\PictureHeight{24cm}
\setlength\PictureHeight{0.5\PictureHeight}

\end{document}
```